# SAS: how to change the order of a categorical variable

Tags: sas, levels

To make it simple let's say I have a dataset consiting of four names: Anna, Bobby , Casper, Christine. The column name is just 'Names'.

I want to sort it in this order: Bobby, Anna, Casper, Christine. I cant use 'proc sort' with 'asc/desc' here. Because it's ordered randomly I need to type in the order manually.

Can I somehow include it the following proc sort statement?

```
 Proc Sort
  data = dataset; order by Names;
run;
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But try to add another column, for example with number like : 1 for Bobby, 2 for Anna, 3 for Casper and 4 for Christine ... then sort by the new column.

Comment: @D.O. Thx^. I thought about myself, but that I figured there must be a more sophisticated method. SAS is dissapointing big time, if it's not possible :)

Comment: Your confusion is that you think you have a categorical variable type - you don't, you have a character variable type.

Comment: And @D.O. - it _is_ possible to get SAS to sort this however; look up translation tables (TRANTAB).  It's not the right way to solve _this_ problem, but it is in theory possible, just a way-overly-complicated way to solve a simple situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from @Joe is the best way due to being scalable and the ability to read in formats from a dataset using CNTLIN.  I just thought I'd post an alternative solution, using `proc sql`.  The version SAS uses enables you to create a custom order on the fly by adding an `order by` statement along with a `case` statement.  Effectively this creates an extra column in memory which is used to sort on, but the column is not output.

This is a useful method when the number of items to sort on is relatively small.

```
proc sql;
create table want 
as select *
from have
order by case names
            when 'Bobby' then 1
            when 'Anna' then 2
            when 'Casper' then 3
            when 'Christine' then 4
        end;
quit;
```

Comment: Even if I were doing this in SQL, I'd rather put that into a format than into the case statement - cleaner that way (i.e., `order by input(names,ORDERINFORMATI.)` or similar).

Answer (score 3):

The way you should store categorical variables in SAS is as numerics, with formats to show the characters.  This is how other programming languages, e.g. R, handle them (`factor` in R).

So for example:

```
data have;
  length names $15;
  input names $;
  datalines;
Bobby
Anna
Casper
Christine
;;;;
run;

proc format;
  value yourformatf
   1 = 'Bobby'
   2 = 'Anna'
   3 = 'Casper'
   4 = 'Christine'
   other = ' '
   ;
  invalue yourinformati
   'Bobby' = 1
   'Anna' = 2
   'Casper' = 3
   'Christine' = 4
   other = .
   ;

quit;

data want;
  set have;
  names_cat = input(names,yourinformati.);
  format names_cat yourformatf.;
run;
```

Here I create a format and an informat to go back/forth (name to number, number to name).  You can now sort by `names_cat` and it will sort as you want.  You can do this programmatically (creating the format) using a `cntlin` dataset; search here or your search engine of choice for more information on that.

To compare to `r`, if that's what you're familiar with, here the numeric variable is analogous to the values in the factor variable, and the format is analogous to the labels for the levels.  (There is no direct analogue to the levels themselves stored in the metadata, but many SAS procs have options to use the numbers stored in the format in the same way levels would be used in R.)